# Introspection in Jinja template in SaltStack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

We'd like to add some boilerplate information to file written to minions via Salt; basically, notice that the file is managed by Salt, and the state that generates it.

I can't find the state information. It doesn't appear to be in `opts`. `salt-call state.sls foo` provides what I'm looking for, but `state.sls` doesn't appear callable from a Jinja template.

Am I missing it somewhere? Or is this not possible without, say, writing a Jinja extension that digs around in Salt's sandbox?

Comment: I have the same needs, basically. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if [salt.renderers.jinja#debugging](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#debugging) provides what you need?

Comment: #debugging tag no longer exists at link. Have a better reference?